# How to highlight page number of selected page for a linkbutton inside a repeater using pagedatasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to highlight the current page number selected.

ASPX code:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptPaging" runat="server" onitemcommand="rptPaging_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>                             
             <asp:LinkButton ID="btnPage"  CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" ><%# Container.DataItem %>
              </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Backend code:

```
protected void rptPaging_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName == "Page")
    {    

         int index = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        for (int i = 0; i < rptPaging.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            LinkButton btnlnk = rptPaging.Items[i].FindControl("btnPage") as LinkButton;
            if (btnlnk != null)
            {
                btnlnk.CssClass = index == i ? "page_enabled" : string.Empty;
            }
        }

        PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
        DisplayData();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have css with .page_enabled class somewhere attached to your site? You can check with firebug whether the class is on your element and whether it is present in your css styles

Answer (score 0):

Add an attribute.. onclick="OnClickPageBtnLink(this)" the LinkButton. Use the javascript function:

```
function OnClickPageBtnLink(sender)
{
   sender.class = "YourHighlightClass";

   var pageLinks = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

   for (var i = 0; i < pageLinks.length; i++)
   {
     if (sender.id != pageLinks[i].id)
     {
       if (pageLinks[i].id.indexOf('rptPaging_btnPage_') != 0)
       {
          pageLinks[i].class = "UnHighlightClass";
       }
     }           
   }
}
```

You may also use document.queryFor.. (I am not sure of the syntax) to get the client generated anchor elements. This is definitely not a standard answer, but it would work.

Answer (score -1):

Move the following code:

```
PageNumber = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) - 1;
DisplayData();
```

Above from:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Page")
```

It will definitely work.